# Is it possible to write json data to a file in azure blob storage without converting it to string?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm working on a project in azure databricks where I need to write my transformed data which is in JSON format to a file(.json) which further is written to DB.

I've tried with dataframes,rdd options. some snippets of the things I've tried

```
df.collect.map( line => {
      //transformation logic to create json

      (field1,field2,json);
```

})

```
var dataframe = processedList.toList.toDF("f1","f2","json");
dataframe .repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").json(path)
```

This code works fine but the 'value' which is json data is treated/written as String as it contains all the escape characters etc. Cannot directly use JsonObject as dataframe doesn't support it.

So is there a way to write to the file without it converting to String?

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of `json` column? It's probably `string`, thus Spark treats it as a string literal. Try

```
df.withColumn(to_json("json").alias("json")).write.json(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this solution, but since my dataframe column is stringtype as you rightly pointed out, it is giving error as  "".cannot resolve 'structstojson(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: Input type string must be a struct, array of structs or a map or array of map.;  Is there a way to create different type dataframe column as my json doesn't have a fixed format. Any suggestion?